# Issue changing notebook synced account

Tags: sync, microsoft-onenote

I've been using OneNote for some years now to collect Notes. My organization needed to delete all Microsoft accounts and remake them at one point, so the notebooks I had synced to that account now no longer have an account to sync to, resulting in a syncing error (code `0xE0001462 bukxq 19999`).
My problem however, is that I have no way of changing the account my notebooks tries to sync to. Copying / moving the sections to a new, synced notebook isn't possible either. The syncing error prevents this.

I am using OneNote for Windows so there is no export option. Attempts to move App files between OneNote for Windows and OneNote 2016 to hack the notebooks into that app have failed. Research on the Internet hasn't helped beyond what I've tried either.

Comment: If you're wanting to remove the *activation* account and replace it with your new account, this can be done (I did it about 2 weeks ago), however I can't find the article that I used to help me do it :(. I believe I just had to find a way to deregister or deactivate the current install, and then when I started it again, it asked me to log in to verify licence

Comment: @Smock My goal is, to get my notebooks to sync again. The first account is no longer existing, so there is nothing to remove in the first place. (If that's what you mean?) But thanks for the effort!

Comment: Do you still have the copy of the OneNote file wich contains the entire notebook? That is the key.

Comment: I don’t know if I get what you’re asking about. I’ve got my two notebooks completely functioning in OneNote for Windows. I don’t have any fancy exported Files of them, but the program must have them somewhere... Info in the Internet didn’t help with moving ON’s working-files around, sadly